State not updating correctly when using multiple if statements
const IMETrainer = (props) => {  
    
    // ROOT STATES
    const [firstString, setFirstString] = useState(true);
    const [secondString, setSecondString] = useState(true);
    const [thirdString, setThirdString] = useState(true);
    const [fourthString, setFourthString] = useState(true);
    const [fifthString, setFifthString] = useState(true);
    const [sixthString, setSixthString] = useState(true);    

   // ROOT HANDLERS
    const firstStringHandler = () => {
        setFirstString(!firstString);
        updateRoots();
    }

    const secondStringHandler = () => {
        setSecondString(!secondString);
        updateRoots();
    }

    const thirdStringHandler = () => {
        setThirdString(!thirdString);
        updateRoots();
    }

    const fourthStringHandler = () => {
        setFourthString(!fourthString);
        updateRoots();
    }

    const fifthStringHandler = () => {
        setFifthString(!fifthString);
        updateRoots();
    }

    const sixthStringHandler = () => {
        setSixthString(!sixthString);
        updateRoots();
    }   

    const updateRoots = () => {
        var selectedRoots = [];
        if (firstString == true) {
            selectedRoots.push(1);
        }
        if (secondString == true) {
            selectedRoots.push(2);
        }
        if (thirdString == true) {
            selectedRoots.push(3);
        }
        if (fourthString == true) {
            selectedRoots.push(4);
        }
        if (fifthString == true) {
            selectedRoots.push(5);
        }
        if (sixthString == true) {
            selectedRoots.push(6);
        }
        console.log(selectedRoots);
        setRoots(selectedRoots);
    }
    // SELECTED OPTIONS
    const [roots, setRoots] = useState([1,2,3,4,5,6]);


No matter what I try I cannot get state to update the 'roots' array correctly. I keep getting weird behaviors. I know that state is updating correctly when I toggle the 1-6 buttons, but what am I doing wrong here?
I am expecting to see '1' removed from the array. Clicking the option button toggles each state between true & false.
I'm still unable to figure this out after troubleshooting for several hours.

Try to use a useEffect cmd respect of the setRoots variable

I tried useEffect before posting to no avail, same behaviors

To be honest, just post the full component code (at least the rendering that actually involves this state variable, not just the call to a setter). Functional components have conditions around order of calls, and class components have their own pitfalls.

The string of "1" == true passes. The string of "1" === true is false. Loose and strict equality in js is funky

We need the whole component, this isnt enough context.

updated to show component

I am not sure but I think it has something to do with internal React optimizations. There are lots of states, which could be combined. Try (You can run the following snippet to see it effect) =>


const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const IMETrainer = (props) => {

  // ROOT STATES
  const [aString, setaString] = useState({
    firstString: true,
    secondString: true,
    thirdString: true,
    fourthString: true,
    fifthString: true,
    sixthString: true,
  });

  // ROOT HANDLERS

  function mustt(event) {
    let c = aString;
    switch (event.target.innerText) {
      case "firstStringHandler":
        c["firstString"] = false;
        setaString(c);
        updateRoots();
        break;

      case "secondStringHandler":
        c["secondString"] = false;
        setaString(c);
        updateRoots();
        break;

      case "thirdStringHandler":
        c["thirdString"] = false;
        setaString(c);
        updateRoots();
        break;

      case "fourthStringHandler":
        c["fourthString"] = false;
        setaString(c);
        updateRoots();
        break;

      case "fifthStringHandler":
        c["fifthString"] = false;
        setaString(c);
        updateRoots();
        break;

      case "sixthStringHandler":
        c["sixthString"] = false;
        setaString(c);
        updateRoots();
        break;
    }
  }

  const updateRoots = () => {
    var selectedRoots = [];
    if (aString.firstString == true) {
      selectedRoots.push(1);
    }
    if (aString.secondString == true) {
      selectedRoots.push(2);
    }
    if (aString.thirdString == true) {
      selectedRoots.push(3);
    }
    if (aString.fourthString == true) {
      selectedRoots.push(4);
    }
    if (aString.fifthString == true) {
      selectedRoots.push(5);
    }
    if (aString.sixthString == true) {
      selectedRoots.push(6);
    }
    console.clear();
    console.log(selectedRoots);
  };

  function Butn({ name }) {
    return <button onClick={(event) => mustt(event)}> {name} </button>;
  }

  const btn = handlers.map((a) => <Butn name={a} />);

  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <div className="container"> {btn} </div>{" "}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<IMETrainer />);
.parent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  flex-basis: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container>button {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script> const handlers = [
    "firstStringHandler",
    "secondStringHandler",
    "thirdStringHandler",
    "fourthStringHandler",
    "fifthStringHandler",
    "sixthStringHandler",
  ];
</script>

<div id="app"></div>




  useEffect(() => {
    updateRoots();
}, [firstString, secondString, thirdString, fourthString, fifthString, sixthString])

using useEffect in the above way solved the issue - the updateRoots function works perfectly now
